How can I run fullscreen games in Wine?
I am new into Ubuntu and I am having some issues running games such as GTA San Andreas under Wine. The problem is that the only way to perfectly play the game is to set the resolution of the game to 1920x1080 (my screen's native resolution), but it is a little bit annoying as the HUD is too small for me.
What I am trying to do (just like on Windows) is to run the game in 800x600 or 1024x768 and let the game fill and adapt to my screen. Whenever I try to do something like this on Wine + Ubuntu I get:

a little 800x600 square located at the top-left of the screen when the setting to emulate a virtual screen is uncecked
a little 800x600 window if I check the option for a virtual screen.

So... in both cases (according to solutions I have found on the web) I cannot get the fullscreen I am searching for.
Thanks in advance for your help!
P.S. I am using Ubuntu 24.04

PlayOnLinux is a user friendly method of installing WINE applications on Ubuntu. Try to search for questions (tagged) with PlayOnLinux in them. https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/playonlinux

Start by visiting the Wine HQ and looking up the app or game you want to run under Wine. Not all apps and games run on wine and many have restrictions. This is Wine has their database.
